# Is shallow copy implementation different for python list and pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, list, series, shallow-copy

I know the shallow copy behaviour of list

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = copy(list1) # shallow copy of list1

list1 is list2 # False as expected
False

list1[0] is list2[0] # True as expected
True

list1[0] = 10 # this will change list1 but not list2

# the result is as expected
list1
[10, 2, 3, 4]
list2
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have tried similar operations with `pandas` `series`. The behaviour is different.

```
series1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
series2 = series1.copy(deep=False) # shallow copy

series1 is series2 # as expected
False

series1[0] is series2[0] # Q1: I was expecting True
False

# Q2: I was expecting the change in series1 but not in series2
series1[0] = 10
series1
0    10
1     2
2     3
3     4
dtype: int64

series2
0    10
1     2
2     3
3     4
dtype: int64
```

Question 1: Why `series1[0]` and `series2[0]` is not the same?

Question 2: Why changing first element of `series1` also changed `series2` even though they are different as per Question 1?

Why the behaviour is not consistent for `list` and `series`? Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: `Why the behaviour is not consistent for list and series` - `list` is a Python object, `Series` is a Pandas object - apparently the Pandas Series designers  desired the behaviour they gave it.

Comment: `Why series1[0] and series2[0] is not the same?` - Are you expecting it to be the same object or to have the same value?

Comment: `series1.values is series2.values` -> `True`

Comment: @wwii I was expecting the same object

Comment: @wwii well, they are *both python objects*

Comment: @cryptomanic the key issue is that is **never the case** for `pandas.Series` objects (unless you use dtype=object).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I guess I meant that a list is a Python object in the sense that it is part of the language, it can be found in the Python [standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) whereas a Pandas Series object is not part of the (core?) language and was designed by (probably) different people for a different purpose. You're tryin' to trick me - ??

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue here is that `pandas` is essentially a wrapper around a `numpy.ndarray`, which, for arrays which use actual numeric dtypes instead of dtype=object, then the primitive values need to be "boxed" every time you index. So note, this is the behavior *without copying at all*:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([1])
>>> s[0] is s[0]
False
```

Note, the behavior becomes consistent with `dtype=object`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1], dtype=object)
>>> s[0] is s[0]
True
>>> import copy
>>> copy.copy(s)[0] is s[0]
True
```